# Async PCL assmeblies mismatch

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, async-await, portable-class-library

I have a PCL Project with makes use of the Microsoft.Bcl.Async Nuget package that has some common code. Now when I reference the assembly and use some of the async methods in my WP8 project I get the following error :

```
Cannot convert source type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> [System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]' to target type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> [mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]'
```

I have tried adding the following assembly binding and also adding the Microsoft.Bcl.Async Nuget package to my WP8 project, but nothing seems to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.11.0" newVersion="1.5.11.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.11.0" newVersion="1.5.11.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong, or what else I could try?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

1. Uninstalling the package everywhere
2. Removing any binding redirects that refer to System.Runtime, System.Threading.Tasks or Microsoft.Threading.* from all projects.
3. Reinstall the package in every project including the WP8 project

There should be no binding redirects in the WP8 project referring to System.* - if there are, remove them also (you might be hitting https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3072).